# How can I create scoped environment variables in my Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-shared-libraries

The Jenkins credentials plugin provides a `withCredentials` function that can store the value of a credential into a scoped environment variable as seen [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/).

```
node {
  withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'mylogin', variable: 'USERPASS')]) {
    sh '''
      set +x
      curl -u "$USERPASS" https://private.server/ > output
    '''
  }
}
```

I want to write a groovy method we store in our Jenkins vars shared library that does something similar; a list of pairs for an ID to operate on and the name of an environment variable to store that ID within scope of the function. Something like

```
withMyOwnVars([
    ['some-input', 'VAR_NAME'],  // Value of VAR_NAME will be set under the hood somehow.
    ['another-one', 'VAR2']
])
{
    print("$VAR_NAME")
}
```

Does Groovy provide this functionality?

Comment: How can you create ... what?

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve what you want is to define a function that receives the input parameters (as some form of key value) alongside a Closure and uses the [evaluate](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.7/html/gapi/groovy/lang/Script.html#evaluate(java.lang.String)) function to define the given parameters at runtime, thus making them available inside the closure.

Something like:

```groovy
def withMyOwnVars(Map args, Closure body){
    args.each {
        // Define the name and value of the parameter. For strings, add quotes to make them evaluate correctly
        def paramName = it.key
        def paramValue = (it.value instanceof CharSequence) ? "'${it.value}'" : it.value

        // Run the evaluation of the parameter definition to make them available in the function's scope
        evaluate("${paramName} = ${paramValue}")
    }
    body()
}


// Usage will look like the following
withMyOwnVars(['myParam': 'my value', 'anotherParam': 6]) {
    println "I can now use myParam, and the value is ${myParam}"
    def result = 10 + anotherParam
}
```

Or using your requested input format:

```groovy
def withMyOwnVars(List args, Closure body){
    args.each { item ->
        def paramName = item[0]
        def paramValue = (item[1] instanceof CharSequence) ? "'${item[1]}'" : item[1]
        evaluate("${paramName} = ${paramValue}")
    }
    body()
}

// Usage will look like the following
withMyOwnVars([['myParam', 'my value'], ['anotherParam', 6]]) {
    println "I can now use myParam, and the value is ${myParam}"
    def result = 10 + anotherParam
}
```